# Understanding SerDe information when building table in AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, parquet

I'm defining a table in cloudformation which will output to an aws glue data catalog. While I understand most of the resource properites, I don't understand the parts related to SerDe. I'm using this code in my template to help me create a table. [image: cloudformation template code]

I'm also having difficulty finding information related to this code as AWS' documentation doesn't explain it very well. At least I'm having difficulty understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in the past and the solution in my case was to use the documentation for Athena service. Athena service is integrated with Glue Data Catalog.
[Amazon Athena - SerDe reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/serde-reference.html)

In addition to that Glue Data Catalog is compatible with the Apache Hive metastore, so you can use Apache Hive metastore documentation. In Amazon Athena - SerDe reference, you will also find links to external sources.

I hope this information will be useful to you